# What config file does appcmd.exe update?

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7.5, appcmd

When running `appcmd.exe` commands from the command prompt, is there a config file getting updated somewhere? If so, where is that file?

For example, I ran the following:

`appcmd.exe set config "MyWebsite" -section:system.webServer/modules -runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests:true`

It's great that running the command solved my problem, I just don't know what actually changed? Is this a setting I can see from within IIS or was there a config file somewhere that changed? I thought I'd see the `ApplicationHost.config` file get updated, but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track what changed and when, you may want to turn on Configuration Auditing as described in [IIS 7.5 – How to enable IIS Configuration Auditing?](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/19/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-iis-configuration-auditing.aspx) rather than looking for changes to files.

Also, remember that some setting changes, particularly where they refer to a specific site, will occur in the web.config file. See [Modules <modules>](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules) for documentation that relates to the command line you gave as your example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into the auditing feature, it looks like it could be useful. As for my changes, since they were for a specific site I checked the Web.config at the site level, and the application level - and neither were updated. That's why I looked at the ApplicationHost.config, but that didn't change either.

Comment: Nevermind - I found it. It was in the Web.config at my site level, but for some reason the timestamp on the file was like an hour off? That's why I assumed it hadn't been updated, but sure enough that attribute from the command I ran was in there...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it configures the [IIS Metabase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240941). There used to be a metabase.xml in the past but I don't know about IIS7.

Comment: In that article, it says that Metabase is specific to "Internet Information Server version 4.0" so I doubt this is what I'm looking for but thanks for the reply!

Comment: Good call. I didn't realise that the old metabase was not in IIS7+.

Comment: I believe IIS 7 use a xml based config system, with files named *.config

Comment: Yes, the metabase is no more. Appcmd is a command line tool for updating config files in the new configuration file system that replaces the metabase.